# How to get serialize the model in django REST

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the django Model

```
class User(models.Model):
    def serialize(self):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=self)
        if serializer.is_valid():

           return serializer.data
```

basically i want to get the serialized version of current model instance

```
obj = User.objects.get(pk=1)
obj.serialize()
```

`but i get error that serializers expects Dict u gave User`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not pass `data` param, in this case, you just need to pass the object:

```
def serialize(self):
    serializer = UserSerializer(self)
    if serializer.is_valid():

       return serializer.data
```

As you can see here in [Serializing Objects section](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)

Comment: I am using Hyperlinkserializer so then it gave me this error  `HyperlinkedIdentityField` requires the request in the serializer context. Add `context={'request': request}`  , but i don't have request . is there any way

Comment: Yes you will need to call the serializer inside your view, or pass the request to the `serialize` method -> `obj.serialize(request=request)` and pass it to serializer's context.